# Filtering the number of pictures per month of a time series in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, filter

I'm calculating the NDVI of a time series (1 year) of Sentinel-2, but I only want two images per month to calculate that instead of the whole collection of images with less than 75% cloud.

```
//NDVI for Sentinel 2

//Call shapefile 

Map.addLayer(table, {}, 'aneis', true)

// Create image collection of S-2 imagery for the perdiod studied
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')

//filter start and end date
.filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 75))
.filterDate('2018-08-08', '2019-08-08')

//filter according to shapefile
.filterBounds(table);

// this generates a JSON list of the images (and their metadata) which the filters found in the right-hand window.
print(S2) 

// Function to calculate and add an NDVI band
var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']));
};

// Add NDVI band to image collection
var S2 = S2.map(addNDVI);
// Extract NDVI band and create NDVI median composite image
var NDVI = S2.select(['nd']);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median(); //I just changed the name of this variable ;)

// Create palettes for display of NDVI
var ndvi_pal = ['#d73027', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#d9ef8b',
'#a6d96a'];

// Create a time series chart.
var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(S2, table,ee.Reducer.mean(),
'nd',500,'system:time_start', 'system:index')
              .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
                title: 'NDVI short-term time series',
               hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
                vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'}
});

// Display.
print(plotNDVI);

// Display NDVI results on map
Map.addLayer(NDVImed.clip(table), {min:-0.5, max:0.9, palette: ndvi_pal}, 'NDVI');
```

Comment: The first two images? Least cloudy? Please specify.